# eigen: Subtracting a scalar from a vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I am having an error when using the Eigen library and all I am trying to do is subtract a scalar from an Eigen::VectorXf. So, my code is something as follows:

```
#define VECTOR_TYPE Eigen::VectorXf
#define MATRIX_TYPE Eigen::MatrixXf

// myMat is of MATRIX_TYPE
JacobiSVD<MATRIX_TYPE> jacobi_svd(myMat,ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV); 

const float offset = 3.0f;
VECTOR_TYPE singular_values = jacobi_svd.singularValues();

VECTOR_TYPE test = singular_values - offset;
```

The last line results in a compilation error as:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Eigen::VectorXf' (aka
>         'Matrix') and 'float')
>           VECTOR_TYPE test = singular_values - scale;
>
> Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/CommonCwiseBinaryOps.h:19:28: note: 
>         candidate template ignored: could not match
>         'MatrixBase' against 'float'
>       EIGEN_MAKE_CWISE_BINARY_OP(operator-,internal::scalar_difference_op)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simplest is to move to the so called ["array"](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) world:

```
VECTOR_TYPE test = singular_values.array() - offset;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Creating a vector of ones has a runtime cost, while the conversion to array doesn't.

Answer (score 13):

It's mathematically invalid to subtract a scalar (which is just a one-dimensional vector) from a vector, so Eigen correctly throws an error.

Instead, you should write

```
auto n = singular_values.size();
VECTOR_TYPE test = singular_values - offset * VECTOR_TYPE::Ones(n);
```

Moreover, you can have a look at the `array()` functionality which provides element-wise transformations.

Comment: You should make your answer only about the conversion to an array. Creating a vector of ones and multiplying is unnecessarily complex and has a runtime cost, while the conversion to array doesn't: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html#title6

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken you can also use a broadcasting operation:

```
VECTOR_TYPE test = singular_values.rowwise() - offset;
```

Comment: I agree with raaj.  You cannot broadcast between a vector and scalar like that.  @ggael has the best answer, using array().